# How to ignore exceptions while testing "autoload" with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, exception, phpunit

Story:

So I am trying to implement autoloader for my application that will throw exception in case if file within namespace not found, and in test i am just checking is this class exists or not... well i am trying to check it.

My problem, that the exception i am throwing in autoloaded, not ignored in test... and i am getting error during testing. **But isn't my exception are in try catch block should be ignored by PHPUnit?**

```
spl_autoload_register( function ( $class_name ) {
    if ( strpos( $class_name, 'App' ) !== false ) {

        $class_file = strtolower( $class_name );
        $class_file = str_replace( '\\', '-', $class_file );

        $class_file  = str_replace( 'app-', '', $class_file );
        $class_file  = sprintf( 'class-%s.php', $class_file );
        $class_file  = dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/includes/' . $class_file;

        if ( file_exists( $class_file ) ) {
            include_once $class_file;
            if ( ! class_exists( $class_name ) ) {
                throw new Exception( sprintf( 'Can\'t load %s class.', $class_name ));
            }
        } else {
            // do not throw path of the file.
            throw new Exception( sprintf( 'Can\'t find %s class file.', $class_name ) );
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see its quite simple code.

```
require dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ExceptionsTest extends TestCase {

    /**
     * @dataProvider data_existing_namespace
     */
    public function test_existing_namespaces( $class_name, $class_exists ) {

        try {

            $object = new $class_name();
            if ( $class_exists === true ){
                $this->assertTrue(  class_exists( $class_name ) );
            } else {
                $this->assertFalse( class_exists( $class_name ) );
            }

        } catch( Exception $e ) {
            // do nothing.
        }
    }


    /**
     * Data provider for test_Namespace_Autoload
     */
    public function data_existing_namespace() {
        return [
            [ '\App', true ],
            [ '\App\Settings', false ],
        ];

    }
}
```

but... I still getting this error, which I should (if I understand right) catch.

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\ExceptionTest::test_existing_namespaces with data set #1 ('\App\Settings', false)
Exception: Can't find App\Settings class file.
```

**What can I do to suppers this error and just use AssertFalse or AssertTrue ?**

Comment: try removing the statement `$object = new $class_name();` in the test class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only catching the `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase\Exception` because your test is in this namespace and you just use `Exception` without any namespace or use statement.

You simply have to specify the full namespace to your exception f.e. `\Exception` or you can use a `use` statement like `use Exception;` on top of your file.

```
try {

    $object = new $class_name();
    if ( $class_exists === true ){
        $this->assertTrue(  class_exists( $class_name ) );
    } else {
        $this->assertFalse( class_exists( $class_name ) );
    }

// catch all exception possible \Excecption
// maybe use \My\Namespace\Exception or something
} catch( \Exception $e ) {
    // do nothing.
}
```

PS:
I would recommend to use the PSR autoloader feature provided by composer to make `vendor/autoload.php` load your classes as well.
So you don't have to implement your own autoloader, and you are using only the one provided by composer. All you have to to is to implement the PSR0 or PSR4 style to name and structure your class files.

Have a look at the documentation here https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload

Comment: Yeah, looks like i just miss \ before default Exception. 
thanks!